# python-social-auth failure on Google App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-social-auth, djangoappengine

I am attempting to follow [Tutorial: Adding Facebook/Twitter/Google Authentication to a Django Application](http://artandlogic.com/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/). The only thing I am doing differently is that I am running DjangoAppEngine on the Google App Engine development server, otherwise everything is exactly as per the tutorial.

When I get to Step 4 and actually try to authenticate with Facebook, I am getting a runtime error:

```
error('illegal IP address string passed to inet_pton',)

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localtest.com:8080/o/complete/facebook/?redirect_state=FG4K...UG1k
Django Version: 1.6.11
Exception Type: RuntimeError
Exception Location: /Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py in _MakeRealSyncCall, line 235
Python Executable:  /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.11
```

Obviously FB is passing an approval back to my app, as the request URL includes the callback path.

It appears that something in the GoogleAppEngineLauncher is trying to look up an address and is not receiving the right data in? I'm not really sure.

In trying to resolve this, I've come across a single comment somewhere suggesting to a user that [SimpleAuth](https://simpleauth.appspot.com/) might be a better way to go, but I don't understand why and I'm not really sure I want to start over if I am just missing something obvious.

Does anyone know why I am getting this error and what I can do to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: the original answer (starting with 'HOWEVER') is no longer necessary, just use `requests` 2.10.0 or above, `urllib3` 1.15.1 or above, and `requests_toolbelt` 0.6.2 or above and perform the following in your main():

```
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine
appengine.monkeypatch()
```

**HOWEVER** if you're using older versions of requests and/or urllib3, then you need the patches below:

This can be accomplished using a patched version of `requests` along with the `requests-toolbelt` package. Threads that apply:

- [HTTPS not working on Google App Engine #1905](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1905)
- [urllib3 / Contrib Modules / Google App Engine](http://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contrib.html#google-app-engine)
- [Fixes the AppEngineManager to work within the requests framework #763](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/763)
- [Add AppEngineAdapter for GAE users #114](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt/pull/114)
- [Adds a monkeypatch() function that ensures all Sessions use the AppEngineAdapter compatibility class. #119](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt/pull/119)

I've applied all of this and now have `python-social-auth` and `facebook-sdk` working in both local test (the dev server) and production (full App Engine).

Comment: which patches did you apply, exactly?

Comment: I confirm that this works. The key is the last link: https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt/pull/119

Comment: Hopefully all these patches will be rolled into the official versions of these libraries soon and no patching will be necessary :)

Comment: requests 2.10.0 is out and works great! i just upgraded to it and urllib3 1.15.1 and run `from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine; appengine.monkeypatch()` up front. no other hacks or patches needed. thanks!

Comment: excellent, thanks for the update. I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the Facebook SDK depends on the awesome `requests` library. However, `requests` doesn't work on Google App Engine since the platform has some restrictions. You have to use their `urlfetch` APIs to fetch external contents on Google App Engine.

So yes, the official Facebook SDK won't work. You have to roll your own solution or find one that works. `SimpleAuth` is one of the solution that is known to have worked.

Comment: Well, that sucks... but in general I am totally comfortable with the sandbox, just hadn't realized that was what was going on. OK, `SimpleAuth` it is. Thanks!

Comment: `requests` now works under App Engine (with a few patches)... I've replaced the answer to include links to the relevant docs.

Answer (score 0):

In your vendored libraries, ensure that you have requests_toolbelt. (`pip install -t lib requests_toolbelt`).  Then "monkeypatch" appengine support before python-social-auth ever calls requests.  In my project/wsgi.py, I added the following lines:

```
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import appengine
appengine.monkeypatch()
```

python-social-auth depends on `requests`, so it should also exist in your vendor directory.

You must also ensure you are using requests version >= 2.10.0.  This has not been released yet, so you can fake it.  Edit `lib/requests/__init__.py` so that `__build__ = 0x021000`.  You also must upgrade the packaged version of `urllib3` in the `lib/requests/packages/` directory to the latest version.

This is what worked for me.

Comment: I tried all this and it didn't work for me, with GAE SDK 1.9.36

Comment: works for me! with urllib3 1.15.1. [details below.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34574740/python-social-auth-failure-on-google-app-engine/35944044#comment61501928_35109359)

Comment: This wasn't working for me with the latest GAE SDK either. I rolled back to a version around January 2016 (gcloud 94.0.0, GAE 1.9.31) at it started working

Comment: If you are still getting this issue, but get an SSL issue with v 94.0.0, update to gcloud v 100.0.0, which is the last version that works before the `error('illegal IP address string passed to inet_pton',)`

Comment: Another update: still not fixed, but, instead of downgrading your version of the SDK, there is a patch that you can apply to your app engine sdk to resolve the issue. Details on the related issue in their issue tracker: 
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12582

Comment: Odd, both of my other team members have run up against this. Are you using gcloud or just the app engine sdk? Which version number? operating system?